# Pivot SQL when a character exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd like to have a query which resulted in a new column always when I find the character '    -    '

Example:

```
WITH Test as (
SELECT 'Robert - Plant' as name union all
SELECT 'Mary - Elizabeth -Smith' as name union all
SELECT 'Cristian - Lord Gray, Tyson' as name
)

SELECT Name
FROM Test
```

It should be:

```
Name1, Name 2, Name 3, name4
Robert, Plant, Null, Null
Mary, Elizabeth, Smith, Null
Cristian, Lord, Gray, Tyson
```

Comment: You can construct dynamic SQL but it'll have to process all of the data twice. Any *particular* query will always generate a result set with a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their names and types. So dynamic SQL can write you a new query based on your data but you'll first have to go through and work out *how many* columns will be needed. Ideally, stop breaking basic normalization and storing multiple data items in a single column.

Comment: Saw your second request with a single delimeter.  See edit in my answer for a cleaner example

Answer (score 2):

Cross Apply B will create a "CleanString" delimited with spaces.

Cross Apply C will parse the clean string

**Example**

```
WITH Test as (
SELECT 'Robert - Plant' as name union all
SELECT 'Mary - Elizabeth -Smith' as name union all
SELECT 'Cristian - Lord Gray, Tyson' as name
)


Select Name
      ,C.*
 From  Test A
 Cross Apply (values (ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(Name,'-',' '),',',' '),' ','†‡'),'‡†',''),'†‡',' ')))) ) B(CleanString)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(CleanString,' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
Name                            Pos1        Pos2        Pos3    Pos4    Pos5
Robert - Plant                  Robert      Plant       NULL    NULL    NULL
Mary - Elizabeth -Smith         Mary        Elizabeth   Smith   NULL    NULL
Cristian - Lord Gray, Tyson     Cristian    Lord        Gray    Tyson   NULL
```

> **EDIT - Saw your 2nd Qustion with a single delimter**

```
WITH TEST AS
  (SELECT 'AAAA - BBBBB - CCCC- DDDD' AS Name
   UNION ALL SELECT 'EEEE - GGGGG - FFFF' AS Name
   UNION ALL SELECT 'EEEE - RRRR -' AS Name
   UNION ALL SELECT 'LLLL - WWWW - IIII- TTTT' AS Name
   UNION ALL SELECT 'QQQQ' AS Name
  )
SELECT A.Name
      ,B.*
 FROM TEST A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(Name,'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as B1 
             ) B
```